powershell - copy a part of a regex under the line where it has been found
I got a file
fill
---example---
fill
fill
---copy---
fill

and I want to get the text between - and write it below like this
fill
---example---
example
fill
fill
---copy---
copy
fill

Yes, I still want to get my original strings
I tried a lot of things but the closest one I got is this :
$regex = '---(?<text>.*)---'
(Get-Content -Path .\fichier.txt) -replace $regex, "---$($matches['text'])---`n$($matches['text'])" | Set-Content -Path .\fichier.txt

but the file becomes this
fill
---example--- 
example
fill
fill
---example--- 
example
fill

How can I get thru all regex matches ?

The default behavior of Get-Content is: read one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each representing a line of content.
This means that you could simply stream it like:
$regex = '---(?<text>.*)---'
Get-Content .\fichier.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_
    if ($_ -Match $regex) { $matches['text'] }
}

Note that you can't stream the output directly to the same file as you streaming from.
For this you might simply write it to a different file or choke the pipeline by using parenthesis or assigning the content to a variable (which will load everything into memory):
$Content = Get-Content .\fichier.txt | ForEach-Object { ...

And than:
$Content | Set-Content -Path .\fichier.txt 


Yeah I did something like this earlier, but I can't write in the specified file. Maybe I'm missing something ?

I managed to make it work. Thanks for your help
